# Get Assign product collection?

Tags: magento-1.9

We are using Marketplace in my website also some product have **more then one seller**. Even every seller have unique **SKU** How to get that Sku?

If i use this `$products->getSku()` base sku only came not assign seller sku how to get that?

One more thing i got it if product is assigned it have **mpassignproduct_id** it's like unique id so how to get based on that?

```
<?php $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$products->getSku()." </strong> <span>X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";?>
```

It display base Sku Only

Assign Product Table Name marketplace_assignproduct

Product Id name :mpassignproduct_id

[image]

```
public function getpronamebyorder($mageorderid){
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $name='';
        $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$mageorderid); 
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$customerid);   
        foreach($_collection as $res){
                $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid']);
               /*Restrict Character length*/
                $orderdproname = $res['mageproname'];
                $orderdproname = substr($orderdproname,0,20)."..";
                /*Restrict Character length*/
                $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$products->getSku()." </strong> <span>X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";
                //$name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a>"." X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."&nbsp;</p>";
    }   
        return $name;       
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you want to get collection of product based on product id?

Comment: i want to get sku of particular seller

Comment: can you add table information too?

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get collection like below

```
  $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');




 $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id_id=?', $res['mpassignproduct_id']
 )
 ;
 $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);     


if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
 foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
   {   $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$assignproduct['sku']." </strong> <span>X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";

   }} else {
     $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$products->getSku()." </strong> <span>X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";
      }
```

for phtml

```
$customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $name='';
        $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$_order->getRealOrder‌​Id()); 
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$customerid);   
        foreach($_collection as $res){
          $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');




     $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id_id=?', $res->getMpassignproductId()
     )
     ;
     $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
     if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
     foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
       { 
       echo $assignproduct['sku'];
       }



    }
```

Comment: How to fetch here <?php $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$products->getSku()." </strong> <span>X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";?>
 if Product is assigned

Comment: you want for all the product name and sku?

Comment: updated the answer kindly check and feedback.

Comment: It's not working No error it showing only one order

Comment: Check my updated question i added method

Comment: can you `print_r($res);` and paste it too in question so i can what data is coming in that..

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: updated on according to your question update..

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in /var/www/html/videomergerapp/app/code/local/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Saleslist.php on line 496 it show error where i can add this into above method

Comment: can you tell which line is 496 so it can clear where is error..

Comment: can i add with this within for loop

Comment: updated the answer try that and feedback

Comment: can you please tell me where to add plz check my question

Comment: repalce with this `$name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$products->getSku()." </strong> <span>X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";`

Comment: it does not show anything one order only i can't able to see anything

Comment: updated the code kindly check there was error remove check it now and check this model is there Webkul_Marketplace

Comment: How to check this model

Comment: did you use the updated code?

Comment: ya stiil same i can't able to see any thing

Comment: updated the model is not i use the custom query method..

Comment: What is this servicecenters/customervehicle

Comment: remove that copy/paste mistake

Comment: Ya thanks it's working can you please exaplain this

Comment: it is simple your order array have assingproduct id simple matched with you table id and get the data and if data is there show it otherwise show the current product sku

Comment: Ok thanks for explanation in phtml also i used <?php echo $_item->getSku();?> but it getting base sku only how to get seller sku

Comment: It's for .phtml file in question for model file

Comment: you question always have layered of question. need to see the code.

Comment: it is function that returning the $name. where you want this in phtml file

Comment: Yes i want to in .phtml file

Comment: simple call the function name and echo it will display..

Comment: i echo $name but it's not working

Comment: this is block or model function?`getpronamebyorder`

Comment: model function..

Comment: call this `Mage::getModel('modename')->getpronamebyorder('pass order id here');`

Comment: Is it right <?php echo Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getpronamebyorder($_order->getRealOrderId());?>

Comment: getOrderId() not real order id..

Comment: No it not display anything

Comment: is customer is login??

Comment: Customer login ? i can't get

Comment: this function for customer that are login and see their order.

Comment: Yes seller login their dashboard and then see

Comment: pass the real order id then check function is returning something or not

Comment: No it's not display any thing i want only sku not all

Comment: updated the answer try second for direct call

Comment: Now also sku shows empty

Comment: updated code kindly check it..

Comment: Ya i updated but showing empty only

Comment: kidnly debug it by echo something ins first loop then in second

Comment: Ok i will check it thanks for supporting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function getpronamebyorder($mageorderid)
{
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $name='';
        $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$mageorderid); 
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$customerid);   
        foreach($_collection as $res)
        {
            $marketplaces  = Mage::getModel('webkul/marketplace')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $res['mageproid']);
            if(count($marketplaces)){
                foreach($marketplaces as $marketplace) {
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($marketplace->getProductId());   
                    /*Restrict Character length*/
                    $orderdproname = $res['mageproname'];
                    $orderdproname = substr($orderdproname,0,20)."..";
                /*Restrict Character length*/
                $name .= "<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($product->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$product->getSku()." </strong> <span>X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";
                }
            }   
        }

        return $name;       
}
```

Comment: Check my updated question i added that method

Comment: can you share marketplace_assignproduct table model name?

Comment: Webkul_Marketplace

Comment: Update code in fun getpronamebyorder() pls replace above function in your file

Comment: it does not show anything one order only i can't able to see anything